# How do I get Private_Pub working with Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, faye, private-pub

I'm trying to understand how to get private_pub working with Rails 4 using the Readme's Alternative Usage syntax. It's not working for me.

I created a brand new Rails 4 app with a single controller and index action (set as root route).

home_controller.rb

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    PrivatePub.publish_to "/messages/new", :chat_message => "Hello, world!"
  end
end
```

home.js.coffee

```
PrivatePub.subscribe "/messages/new", (data, channel) ->
  alert(data.chat_message)
```

I started the faye server with

> rackup private_pub.ru -s thin -E production

I started the rails server, then went to the root page ("home#index"), and nothing is happening. The faye server is showing that nothing is going on. Based on my understanding, I "should" get an alert box popping up when I visit home#index, but nothing happens and I can't figure out why.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: For you information rails 4 added a new feature actioncontroller live. So you can easily implement the chat application with use of rails 4 live + any one queue server. Please see the sample app https://github.com/mohanraj-ramanujam/live-stream

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of ActionController::Live, but my understanding is that it's not supported by all browsers yet, in particular Internet Explorer. Do you know this to be different?

Comment: No, it does not work with Internet Explorer. Plus the private_gem provides features that ActionController::Live don't. It would be nice to be able to run it on Rails 4.

Answer (score 0):

You may have already solved this, but I figured I'd chime in since I came across your question while trying to fix the same problem.

It seems you still need to `<%= subscribe_to '/messages/new' %>` in your index.html.erb or wahtever view, before calling `PrivatePub.subscribe [...]` in your CoffeeScript

Ryan Bates, in this [old debug ticket](https://github.com/ryanb/private_pub/issues/10), seems to imply that this is the case; he suggests error handling for the case of:

> using `PrivatePub.subscribe` without `subscribe_to` call so messages are never received

... which sounds like the situation you described.

Hope this helps.